# SmsManager.SendMultimediaMessage no longer works with ContentProvider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-mms

In Xamarin.Android, I have setup a custom `ContentProvider` that serves the PDU file to the system when sending an MMS:

```
[ContentProvider(new[] { Authority }, GrantUriPermissions = true)]
internal class MmsUploadContentProvider : ContentProvider
{
    internal const string Authority = "my.package.name.mmsUploads";

    public override ParcelFileDescriptor OpenFile(AndroidUri uri, string mode)
    {
        File uploadsDirectory = GetMmsUploadsDirectory(this.Context);
        File file = new File(uploadsDirectory, uri.LastPathSegment);
        ParcelFileDescriptor result = ParcelFileDescriptor.Open(file, ParcelFileMode.ReadOnly);
        return result;
    }
}
```

I call `SendMultimediaMessage` like so:

```
Uri contentProviderUri = Uri.Parse($"content://{MmsUploadContentProvider.Authority}/{pduFileName}");
smsManager.SendMultimediaMessage(this.Context, contentProviderUri, null, null, statusPendingIntent);
```

However, when my `BroadcastReceiver` is called with the result of the request, it receives a [MMS_ERROR_IO_ERROR](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager#MMS_ERROR_IO_ERROR) result code. In the documentation, it talks about an issue reading the PDU, so I assume there is something wrong with my `ContentProvider`. When I debug, `OpenFile` gets called in my `ContentProvider`, and a proper `ParcelFileDescriptor` gets returned just fine.

Could someone point me in the right direction to fix this? It used to work some years ago, but something must have changed in the Android APIs, causing this to break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those still interested, ultimately the issue was not the `ContentProvider`. The issue was that the file being sent was slightly larger than what MMS allowed in this case. This will throw an [MMS_ERROR_IO_ERROR](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager#MMS_ERROR_IO_ERROR).

The solution I came up with was to first take a look at what [MMS_CONFIG_MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager#MMS_CONFIG_MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE) returned, and gradually compress any media files until the message size went under that limit. I have witnessed that that limit might be lower than the actual maximum size allowed to be sent: I was able to send messages larger than this limit at times. To be on the safe side, I still recommend compressing the MMS up to the limit specified by [MMS_CONFIG_MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager#MMS_CONFIG_MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE) anyway.